# Entrada y salida de datos tipo char* en c

Tags: c, string

El programa es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <string.h>

main()

{

    char* oracion;

    printf( "Escribe una oracion:\n");

    printf( "\nHas escrito: \"%s\"\n", gets(oracion) );

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

El problema está en el último printf, ya que quiero que me devuelva en pantalla
la cadena he ingresado por teclado, pero no funciona, me pueden decir el
porqué?

Comment: Los punteros apuntan a direcciones de memoria. Tu apuntas a una direccion desconocida y ahi es en donde lees la oracion, si es que no se coloca el puntero solo en NULL. Tienes que usar un char[] en lugar del char*.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, la función `gets` retorna cero en caso de éxito y -1 en caso de error. **No** retorna un puntero a la cadena leida.

Segundo, a `gets` le estas pasando un puntero sin inicializar, que puede estar apuntando a cualquier parte. Lo mejor, en este caso, es declarar `oracion` como un arreglo de caracteres de tamaño fijo.

Tercero, `gets` no es recomendable, pues no chequea el largo de la cadena ingresada y puedes terminar escribiendo sobre otros datos.

Lo correcto es usar `fgets`, que tiene la siguiente firma:

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

donde `n` es el número de bytes totales disponibles. La función lee hasta `n-1` bytes y agrega un cero al final para marcar el fin de la cadena.

El código correcto

```
main()
 {
    char oracion[80];

    printf("Escribe una oracion:\n");
    printf("\nHas escrito: \"%s\"\n", fgets(oracion, sizeof(oracion), stdin));
    return 0;
}
```

Nota: `fgets` considera el Enter como parte de la cadena.

Comment: Entonces siempre tengo que indicar el tamaño de la cadena de caracteres? Eso es lo que quería evitar, pero bueno, si no hay otra, muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: @FranciscoMonges puedes usar macros del preprocesador para no tener que escribir el `size` manualmente. *Ejemplo:* `#define gets(array) fgets(array, sizeof array, stdin)`